# Edge can play .BIN audio file. How do I convert it to mp3?

Tags: audio, microsoft-edge, chromium, bin, file-conversion

I want to download an audio file from wistia but it returns as a .bin instead of a traditional mp3/ogg/wav/etc. I know it's an audio file as edge/chromium can play the .bin in the browser when I put the url in its own window. To be as thorough as possible, here is a screenshot of microsoft edge playing the file as audio, even with the bin extension. I've seen that some people suggest using MagicISO, but that doesn't seem to make sense in this case as edge can play the file just fine. Any suggestions would be amazing. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I decided to look through the page source a bit more and since the web debugger said the type is mp3 (inspected the js audio object which held the uri to the file), I decided to just say stuff it and rename the extension to mp3, and voila, it works perfectly. Lesson is to just try rename the file type before looking too deeply into every meaning of a .BIN file.

**Edit**
So I shared my problem with another programmer and he offered a little more insight. Using an Ubuntu distribution, you can see the file type using the *file* command which shows what files are, no matter the extension. So my audio.bin file would’ve showed mp3 despite it’s extension. There are windows equivalents such as [TrID](https://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html).

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community member in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.